# Retrieve class schedule changes from website using python and selenium No Such Element error, ID, XPATH, and more

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My school has a system that tells us if our schedule has any changes.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


url = "https://www.alliancetlv.com/עדכוני-מערכת"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5.0)

examButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'TimeTableView1_btnChanges')
```

im trying to find an element, and later click it using selenium. every time i try to find literally anything it returns No Such Element error. I tried by ID, class name, name, and more.

this is the website: [https://www.alliancetlv.com/עדכוני-מערכת](https://www.alliancetlv.com/%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA)
and im trying to click one of the tabs called "changes/שינויים"

my end goal is to click the dropdown to the side, select a class, click the changes tab, then get all the data inside of it, then maybe format it.

Comment: I even tried by XPATH, copied straight from chrome web tools. didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not seek the element because it is layed inside the iframe. So, you have to:

1. find iframe
2. switch to it
3. find your element
4. click on it

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//iframe[@title='Embedded Content']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//a[contains(@id,'TimeTableView1_btnChanges')]")
elem.click()
```

[See docs...](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/)

Comment: What element is the iframe?

Comment: You can read about iframe here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe and here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP